# how to read a custom part of text from html file in R

Tags: regex, r, rstudio

I have some html text which looks as follows.
I would like to extract the part which says 745 from this text.

I mean, for a different query, the number may be something else(so I'm looking for anything after the word 'of')

```
<div><h2>Search results</h2><h3 class="result_count left">Items: 1 to 20 of 745</h3><span id="result_sel" class="nowrap"></span><input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Spring.Spring_ResultsPanel.Spring_ResultsController.ResultCount" sid="1" type="hidden" id="resultcount" value="745" /><input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Spring.Spring_ResultsPanel.Spring_ResultsController.RunLastQuery" sid="1" type="hidden" /></div>
```

How can I do this using a regular expression in R?

Comment: first, is the HTML structure going to be the same (i.e. this will be HTML output of search results with the same structure)?

Answer (score 0):

A repeatable way that incorporates proper HTML parsing and regular expressions may be:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

search_results <- '<div><h2>Search results</h2><h3 class="result_count left">Items: 1 to 20 of 745</h3><span id="result_sel" class="nowrap"></span><input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Spring.Spring_ResultsPanel.Spring_ResultsController.ResultCount" sid="1" type="hidden" id="resultcount" value="745" /><input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Spring.Spring_ResultsPanel.Spring_ResultsController.RunLastQuery" sid="1" type="hidden" /></div>'
pg <- read_html(search_results)
items <- html_text(html_nodes(pg, "h3.result_count"))
to_val <- as.numeric(str_match(items, "Items: [[:digit:]]+ to [[:digit:]]+ of ([[:digit:]]+)")[,2])
```

depending on the answer to the comment.

One could also mine the `<input>` tag with the `id="result_count"` attribute if that would also be something consistent in the HTML response.